# No application 'AGI' for extension

Tags: asterisk, agi

I haven’t been developing anything for Asterisk for a long time.

Now, I installed Asterisk 16.5.0 on UBUNTU 16.04.
I am trying to run an AGI that I had developed a long time ago but always get (see details below):

```
WARNING: …: No application ‘AGI’ …
```

The extensions.conf looks like this:

[inbound]

exten => 301,1,NoOp()

same => n,Answer()

same => n,AGI( scriptAGI )

same => n,Hangup()

When I disk 301 through xlite I get the following:

[Aug 25 11:13:31] == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5

[Aug 25 11:13:31] WARNING[6788][C-0000000d]: pbx.c:2922 pbx_extension_helper: No application ‘AGI’ for extension (inbound, 301, 3)

[Aug 25 11:13:31] == Spawn extension (inbound, 301, 3) exited non-zero on ‘SIP/asusXlite-0000000c’

[Aug 25 11:13:45] WARNING[1238]: db.c:348 ast_db_put: Couldn’t execute statement: SQL logic error or missing database

I believe this is a configuration issue. Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

The solution to this issue was that AGI needs to have res_speech loaded. I discovered this thanks to the artheops tip. Thank you.
Another point is that spaces before and after the AGI name prevent it from working.

Comment: asterisk -rx "core show application AGI"

Comment: And check for spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `cli` run `core show application AGI`. Then if you are able to see the AGI application, it's working. If you get an error like

> Your application(s) is (are) not registered
>   Command 'core show application AGI' failed.

then try enabling the AGI module in `modules.conf` with the line

`load = res_agi.so`

then go back to `cli` and load the AGI module with `module load res_agi.so`.

Comment: In my case when I tried to run the command `module load res_agi.so` I got the error ```ERROR[12128]: loader.c:283 module_load_error: Error loading module 'res_agi.so', missing dependency: res_speech```.


To solve this problem I added in the `modules.conf` file the definition `load = res_speech.so`, Then I ran in the CLI the command `module load res_speech.so` and only then the `module load res_agi.so` command